# Spring jackson - Map a json to a specific object field

Tags: java, json

i'm trying to deserialize a json string to match an object but i cannot do this with JSONProperties

This is my object

```
 public class Feedback{

    @JsonProperty("event_id")
    private long eventId;

    //getter and setter


    }
```

and the JSON string i get is

```
{..., "event_id":1111111111, ....}
```

When i deserialize the String into `Feedback`, eventId is just skipped...

I deserialize in this way

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Feedback feedback = mapper.readValue(json, Feedback);
```

I have also other fields in Feedback which have the same name of the json field, and they are mapped correctly obviously

Comment: you try to deserialize with event_id  or eventId?

Comment: i need to map event_id to eventId

Comment: post the full qualified name of `Ojbect`. I smell fish.

Comment: Ok i added it, the other fields of Feedback which have the same name of the json fields are mapped correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotate the getter instead of annotating the field:

```
public class Feedback {

    private long eventId;

    @JsonProperty("event_id")
    public long getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(long eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common mistake.
Be sure to use

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

OR

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
```

Mixing the imports will result in issues.

First one is the new version, second one is the old version. Use the first one ;)